# Define custom functions in DDMathParser (Swift)

Tags: swift, function, swift2, customization, ddmathparser

I am attempting to define and format a custom function in Swift via the mechanisms built into DDMathParser. I have tried following the instructions on the Wiki, but for someone who is relatively new to Swift coding there are not enough specifics. The function I want to create would be called "dsi" and would call the already built-in functions sin() and dtor() like so: sin(dtor()).

Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of declaring a custom function can be found [in the unit tests for DDMathParser](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/blob/master/MathParserTests/EvaluatorTests.swift#L261), which I'll include here:

```
func testCustomFunction() {
    let function = Function(name: "foo", evaluator: { (args, subs, eval) throws -> Double in
        return 42
    })

    let eval = Evaluator()
    guard XCTAssertNoThrows(try eval.registerFunction(function)) else { return }
    guard let e = XCTAssertNoThrows(try Expression(string: "foo()")) else { return }
    guard let d = XCTAssertNoThrows(try eval.evaluate(e)) else { return }
    XCTAssertEqual(d, 42)
}
```

You would obviously want to provide a different implementation of the evaluation block passed to the `Function` constructor.

Incidentally, are you aware that DDMathParser has support for the exact case you're describing already? The `Evaluator` object has an `angleMeasurementMode` property. The default value is `.Radians`, [but you can change it to `.Degrees` if you create your own evaluator](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/blob/master/MathParserTests/GithubIssues.swift#L81).

Comment: Much appreciated! And would the function associated with defining a new operator take the same form?